# how group by and filter multiple strings with Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, apply

I'm a beginner for coding and I've tried to look for answers for a few days but I didn't succeed what I want to do so sorry in advance if it's easy or if it already exists somewhere...
Let's say I have a df1 with columns : series_id and lesion_name and I would like to obtain a df2 by replacing the df1 with series_id and lung_ref_seg columns. I can have several lesion_name for the same series_id in df1 (left on the picture). In df2 (right on the picture) I would like to have only one lesion_name for one series_id [original df1 and df2 wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLdVb.jpg). If one series_id has a corresponding lesion_name which has 'lung' and 'PredCorr' I will take this as a first choice for lung_ref_seg. If lesion_name doesn't have 'lung' and 'PredCorr' but has 'lung' and 'From' I will take this as a second choice for lung_ref_seg. And if lesion_name doesn't have any of the two first choices I will take lesion_name which has 'Pred' and 'lung' as a third choice for lung_ref_seg. (lesion_name can have Nan values and I want to keep them in lung_ref_seg). I've tried a lot of things (groupby, filter, str.contains, isin, lambda row...) so I'll just put one code that I think is close to the solution :

```
lesion_name = test['lesion_name']
series_id = test['series_id']

def LungSegRef(lesion_name):
    for rows in series_id:
        if 'PredCorr' in lesion_name and 'lung' in lesion_name:
            return lesion_name
        elif 'PredCorr' not in lesion_name and 'From' in lesion_name and 'lung' in lesion_name:
            return lesion_name
        elif 'PredCorr' not in lesion_name and 'From' not in lesion_name and 'Pred' in lesion_name and 'lung' in lesion_name:
            return lesion_name
    return ''


# Apply the function RefLesionName 
test['lung_ref_seg'] = test['lesion_name'].apply(LungSegRef)
```

With this I don't have errors, I just have Nan values in the whole column lung_ref_seg and I still have multiple same series_id values. So I guess we could use groupby("series_id") somewhere and maybe my argument in the function is wrong. Thank you very much for your help !

The rows are not duplicates. I found something that should work but I'm struggling to differentiate values that contains Pred and PredCorr because when I use contains it doesn't make a difference between rows containing only Pred and rows containing PredCorr. With this code I can't use startswith() and endswith(). I'm trying to find answers with regex but for now I didn't find anything to differentiate rows that contains only Pred and lung compared to rows that contains PredCorr and lung.

```
 def select_row2(row2):
    if row2.lesion_name.str.contains("Pred" and "lung" and "Corr" and "From",na=True).any():
        return row2[row2.lesion_name.str.contains("Corr" and "lung",na=True)]
       
    elif row2.lesion_name.str.contains("Pred" and "lung" and "Corr",na=True).any():
        return row2[row2.lesion_name.str.contains("Corr" and "lung",na=True)]
    
    elif row2.lesion_name.str.contains("lung" and "Corr" and "From",na=True).any():
        return row2[row2.lesion_name.str.contains("Corr" and "lung",na=True)]
    
    elif row2.lesion_name.str.contains("Pred" and "lung" and "From",na=True).any():
        return row2[row2.lesion_name.str.contains("From" and "lung",na=True)]
    
    elif row2.lesion_name.str.contains("Pred" and "lung",na=True).any():
        return row2[row2.lesion_name.str.contains("Pred" and "lung",na=True)]
    
    elif row2.lesion_name.str.contains("lung" and "Corr",na=True).any():
        return row2[row2.lesion_name.str.contains("lung" and "Corr",na=True)]
    
    elif row2.lesion_name.str.contains("lung" and "From",na=True).any():
        return row2[row2.lesion_name.str.contains("lung" and "From",na=True)]
    
    else:
        return None 

test = test.groupby("series_id").apply(select_row2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can approach this as a two step process:

1. First, filter down to the data that you want to keep (it seems like specific values containing specific strings are the one you want - but I'm a bit confused by your post here).
2. Second, drop duplicates from the series_id column. This will result in you just having one value for each of these.

As you mention, filtering using the df.filter function (though you can also do it as `df['lung_ref_seg'] = df[df['lung_ref_seg'].str.contains('STRING TO KEEP')]`.

Dropping duplicates can be done with the `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['series_id'])`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! The rows are not duplicates unfortunately... I edited the post, maybe you can understand a little bit more and help me to differentiate rows containing lung and Pred and rows containing lung and PredCorr ? (More details in the post). Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that seems to work for now !

```
# We remove all lesion_name that contains string "tum" to work on creating the column lung_ref_seg (and we keep nan values)

test = test[~test.lesion_name.str.contains("tum",na=False)]

# Define the function to pick one lesion_name for one series_id prioritizing PredCorr first then From and then Pred for the last choice

def LungRefLesionName(row):
    if row.lesion_name.str.contains("(Pred)\w+" or "From" or "(Pred)\b", na=True).any():
        return row[row.lesion_name.str.contains("(Pred)\w+", na=True)]
        
    elif row.lesion_name.str.contains("From" or "(Pred)\b", na=True).any(): 
        return row[row.lesion_name.str.contains("From", na=True)] 
    
    elif row.lesion_name.str.contains("(Pred)\b" and "lung", na=True).any():
        return row[row.lesion_name.str.contains("(Pred)\b" and "lung", na=True)]

# Apply the function
test = test.groupby("series_id").apply(LungRefLesionName).reset_index(drop=True)


# Drop columns that we don't need anymore : segmentation_id, lesion_id, series_id and study_id

test = test.drop(['segmentation_id', 'lesion_id', 'series_id', 'study_id'], axis = 1)

# Renaming column lesion_name by lung_ref_lesion_name

test = test.rename(columns={"lesion_name": "lung_ref_lesion_name"})
```

I'll have modification to do with lesion_name containing 'tum' later so I guess I'll have to change some things but for now this code works for manipulate strings with 'lung' !